# Regex match until third occurrence of a char is found, counting occurrence of said char starting from the end of string

Tags: regex

Let's dive in : Input :

```
p9_rec_tonly_.cr_called.seg
p9_tonly_.cr_called.seg
p10_nor_nor_.cr_called.seg
p10_rec_tn_.cr_called.seg
p10_tn_.cr_called.seg
p26_rec_nor_nor_.cr_called.seg
p26_rec_tn_.cr_called.seg
p26_tn_.cr_called.seg
```

Desired output :

```
p9_rec
p9
p10_nor
p10_rec
p10
p26_rec_nor
p26_rec
p26
```

Starting from the beginning of my string, I need to match until the third occurrence of " _ " (underscore) is found, but I need to count " _ " (underscore) occurrence starting from end of string.

Any tips is appreciated,

Best regards

Comment: What programming language or tool are you using?

Comment: Currently trying to make this work in Bash

Comment: Your desired output doesn't seem to be matching up until the third "_"

Comment: @JacobBoertjes It's the third, counting backwards, from the right :-)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this regex should do the trick!

```
^.*?(?=_[^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*$)
```

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/73lVkk/4)

---

**Explanation:**

- `^` the start of the line
- `.*?` matches as many characters as possible
- `(?=...)` asserts that its contents follow our match

  - `_[^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*` Looks for exactly three underscores after our match.
  - `$` the end of the line

Answer (score 1):

You should think beyond regex to solve this problem. For example, if you are using Python just use `rsplit` with a limit of 3 and get the first resulting string:

```
>>> data = [
    'p9_rec_tonly_.cr_called.seg',
    'p9_tonly_.cr_called.seg',
    'p10_nor_nor_.cr_called.seg',
    'p10_rec_tn_.cr_called.seg',
    'p10_tn_.cr_called.seg',
    'p26_rec_nor_nor_.cr_called.seg',
    'p26_rec_tn_.cr_called.seg',
    'p26_tn_.cr_called.seg',
]
>>> for d in data:
    print(d.rsplit('_', 3)[0])


p9_rec
p9
p10_nor
p10_rec
p10
p26_rec_nor
p26_rec
p26
```

Comment: The OP only added a comment with that information after I wrote my answer.

Comment: Yes sorry should have mentionned it from the start

Answer (score 1):

`bash` you say? Well it's not a regular expression but you can do pattern substitutions (or stripping with bash):

```
while read var ; do echo ${var%_*_*_*} ; done <<EOT
p9_rec_tonly_.cr_called.seg
p9_tonly_.cr_called.seg
p10_nor_nor_.cr_called.seg
p10_rec_tn_.cr_called.seg
p10_tn_.cr_called.seg
p26_rec_nor_nor_.cr_called.seg
p26_rec_tn_.cr_called.seg
p26_tn_.cr_called.seg
EOT
```

`${var%_*_*_*}` expands variable `var` stripping shorted suffix match for `_*_*_*`.

---

Otherwise to perform regex operations in shell, you could normally ask a utility like `sed` for help and feed your lines through for instance this:

```
sed -e 's#_[^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*$##'
```

or for short:

```
sed -e 's#\(_[^_]*\)\{3\}$##'
```

Find three groups of `_` and zero or more characters of not `_` at the end of line `$` replacing them with nothing (`''`).

Comment: Oh that's even better, ty